# MongooseJS clean string before doing any validations

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I need to clean a string in MongooseJS before doing any type of validation. How can I access a field of my model and alter (clean) the field and only then do the validation of the field?

For instance this is what my model looks like:

```
var NotificationSchema = new Schema({
    topic: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

I want to clean `topic` (remove any whitespace characters from it). After that has been done I want to check that `topic` is minimum 2 characters and maximum 60 characters.

Simply put, I want the topic to be cleaned first thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to validate against the transformed data you can use custom validation. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

```
var NotificationSchema = new Schema({
    topic: { type: String, required: true }
});

NotificationSchema.schema.path('topic').validate(function (value) {
  value = value.replace(/\s/g, '');
  if (value.length > 1 && value.length < 61)
    return true;
  return false;
}, 'Invalid length');
```

If you want to also save the transformed data you would use the pre save hook to do the transform. You will still need to do custom validation as Mongoose doesn't have built in support for string length. See here for middleware docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

```
var NotificationSchema = new Schema({
    topic: { type: String, required: true }
});

NotificationSchema.pre('validate', function(next) {
  this.topic = this.topic.replace(/\s/g, '');
  next();
});

NotificationSchema.schema.path('topic').validate(function (value) {
  if (value.length > 1 && value.length < 61)
    return true;
  return false;
}, 'Invalid length');
```

Comment: So after the validation occurs is the `topic` field removed of all the whitespace? For instance if topic is `whitespace    foo    whitespace`  then it should be saved to the database as `foo`.

Comment: Updated the answer, Validation doesn't modify the data. You will need to use middleware.

Comment: Hmm in what order are the pre save hooks executed? Because I already have a pre save hook and this pre save hook would need to be executed first. I also tried using a setter for the topic but that does not seem to work at all :\

Comment: In order for it to be executed first I put it inside `pre('validate'...)` thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, you're right. Used the wrong pre hook. Was just going to update, but you beat me to it. Good catch.